# htaccess multiple parameters rewrite rule

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know this problem is over asked, but couldnt find anything fitting with my problem.

I'm currently creating a website, and my url are like :

www.foo.com/
or www.foo.com/index.php.
They can take 1, 2 ,or three different parameters like

> www.foo.com/index.php?page=Home&lang=en&article=1

What i'd like is an url like

```
   www.foo.com/Home/

or www.foo.com/en/Home

or www.foo.com/Article/1

or www.foo.com/en/Article/1
```

The page parameter is required, other two are not.. 
I cant have anything working for me... Any help would be greately appreciated

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Better to have separate clean rules. Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$2&lang=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$2&lang=$1&article=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&article=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Where can I learn more about these RewriteRules? i searched but I didnt find a lot of resources.

Comment: @AvinashPatil: https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/ has very good tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

> Try something like this

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)/([a-z0-9_-]+)/([a-z0-9_-]+)\.html$           index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3
```

Comment: i get a 500 internal error, sorry i'm really bad with htaccess files

Comment: There might be an error in htaccess file.please paste ur htaccess file  so i can see it