# .htaccess Doesn't Work for The Second Variable

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm sorry but I'm not really good in Htaccess and PHP

I try to redirect php parameter and it's working fine.

Then I try to rewrite the URL in htaccess but only the first variable works.

Here my PHP (Working fine):

```
$mobile  = $_GET['p'];
$text  = $_GET['t'];
header("Location: https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=".$mobile."&text=".$text);
```

URL: https://example.com/?p=60199788474&t=hai

Then my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?p=$1&t=$2 [NC]
```

If I access: https://example.com/60191111111 then It will redirect properly.

But when i access https://example.com/60191111111/text

then it's won't work.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20468460/htaccess-multiple-parameters-rewrite-rule

Comment: Maybe try `^([0-9]+)\/*.*?$`... You need to account for extra characters at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a regular expression pattern that can match an URI with two segments , currently your rule only matches one

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&t=$2 [NC]
```

Comment: Thanks @starkeen . It's work. Now i wonder how to make the second varible optional.

Eg: example.com/60191111111 and it will redirect only to the first varible and if user put example.com/6019111111/hai it will work also.

Comment: @SyafiqZainal To make it optional you can use `^([0-9]+)/?(.*)/?$` .