# $_GET & .htaccess | PHP ignorer values

Tags: php, .htaccess

I got this problem, where I try to make an Image Archive. Most of it works, but I have now come to prettifying URLs. I have worked with this before, but somehow, it don't work now. If I add more then one Rewrite URL to the same file (index), it ignores the values added with it.

**What I got**:

```
Header add "disablevcache" "true"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteRule ^archive/([^/]+)?$                              archive/index.php?cat=$1 [E=ORIG_URI:/$1]
RewriteRule ^archive/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$                      archive/index.php?cat=$1&sub=$2 [E=ORIG_URI:/$1]
RewriteRule ^archive/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$              archive/index.php?cat=$1&sub=$2&id=$3 [E=ORIG_URI:/$1]
RewriteRule ^archive/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?/([^/]+)$      archive/index.php?cat=$1&sub=$2&id=$3 [E=ORIG_URI:/$1]
```

The following should allow me to access these URLs:

```
domain.com/archive/category
domain.com/archive/category/subcategory/
domain.com/archive/category/subcategory/id
domain.com/archive/category/subcategory/id/item
```

domain.com/archive will be made default, since I use an index.php file, in a folder. And item will just be for SEO and has nothing to do with PHP. (The last rewriteRule)

This works. I can access the same page, from all the different URLs. (archive/index.php). But when I try to use PHP to get the value from the provided URLs, it won't work. I can't even check and see if there are values.

No matter what I do, it just echo out Category & Sub Category on every URL. Also if I go to the default URL, domain.com/archive.

```
if($_GET['cat']){

    echo 'Category';

    if($_GET['sub']){

        echo 'Sub Category';
    }
}
```

Anyone who can see what I am doing wrong or got a suggestion to why it ignore my values? Or maybe know another way to do this, so I end up with the same result?

Comment: Looks like Apache ignores second and the rest of rules by having it matched with first. What happens if you remove first rule and then try to access domain.com/archive/category/subcategory/ ?

Comment: @harisdev If I remove them and leave one rule, it will work. Alredy tried that - but need 4 rules. From what I can see here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20468460/htaccess-multiple-parameters-rewrite-rule that is the way to do it.

Comment: try reversing the rules, start with the longest first, end with the shortest

Comment: @delboy1978uk No difference sadly :-/

Comment: what is this part? [E=ORIG_URI:/$1] have you tried (again in reverse order adding `[L,NC]` (L is last, wont process further upon a match, NC is case insensitivity)

Comment: Is this your whole htaccess?

Comment: @delboy1978uk No clue. It was on another example I followed to begin with. [L,NC] makes no difference, even i reverse.

Comment: @Anonymous Updated with full htaccess in a sec.

Comment: did you remove and replace that part [E=ORIG_URI:/$1] with [L,NC] ?

Comment: @delboy1978uk [L,NC] makes no difference, not even in reversen. Yes i replaced it with [L,NC]. No difference.

Comment: Ah wait, your regexes are broken. hold on!

Comment: look here (this uses named capture groups just as an example) https://regex101.com/r/Pxbb5r/1/

Comment: Here it is without capture groups https://regex101.com/r/Pxbb5r/2 (You might NOT need to backslash the slashes in the htaccess)

Comment: Actually, you probably DO want brackets, just not named ones. https://regex101.com/r/Pxbb5r/3

Comment: Can I get you both to match it up with my code, in a answer? Cant get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache rewrites in a loop. You need to stop it for `archive/index.php` since that always matches the first `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^archive/index\.php$                            - [L]
RewriteRule ^archive/([^/]+)?$                              archive/index.php?cat=$1 [E=ORIG_URI:/$1]
RewriteRule ^archive/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$                      archive/index.php?cat=$1&sub=$2 [E=ORIG_URI:/$1]
RewriteRule ^archive/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$              archive/index.php?cat=$1&sub=$2&id=$3 [E=ORIG_URI:/$1]
RewriteRule ^archive/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?/([^/]+)$      archive/index.php?cat=$1&sub=$2&id=$3 [E=ORIG_URI:/$1]
```

You can also remove `[E=ORIG_URI:/$1]` if you don't use it.

Comment: Thanks you so much!

Comment: Dont know what [E=ORIG_URI:/$1] do, tbh.

Comment: @lol25500 You're welcome! It creates a variable that can be used later. If you don't use that variable, you can remove it.